# Аккордеон на WordPress без плагина, почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Аккордеон на WordЗress без плагина, почему не работает?

Есть статичный аккордеон, мне с его помощью нужно выводить статьи определенной категории WordPress. Взял [этот аккордеон](https://codepen.io/Dwstroy/pen/bLjBze). Я попытался его перенести на WP и Вот что получилось.

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="panel">
      <?php query_posts('cat=8'); 
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <a href="#"><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3></a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
              <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Теперь он не открывается, Но если посмотреть через инструмент разработчика , то можно увидеть, что нужные статьи подгружаются. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Выкинь это немедленно!!! https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/

Comment: Где css и js? На одном html аккордеон не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вставь в шапку (header.php) вот это:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Аккордеон должен заработать. Ну а дальше уже выясняй, почему jquery не подключается на твоем шаблоне как положено.

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо!!!